# Reuse a dictionary entry?

Tags: python

A lib I am using has an annotation with a parameter of:

```
responses: Optional[Dict[Union[int, str], Dict[str, Any]]] = None
```

I am currently using it as follows:

```
responses={
    status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED: {
        "model": UnauthorizedDetail,
        "description": "Unauthorized"
    }
},
```

Is there any syntactic sugar for reusing the dictionary **entry**? i.e. I might have another place where I want to add just 401, but another one after that where I want to add 401, 402, 403 or whatever. i.e. something like:

```
responses={
   the401obj,
   the402obj
}
```

Something where I don't have to keep copying and pasting.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. Could you please [edit] to clarify what you have and how you would like to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
the401entry = {
    status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED: {
        "model": UnauthorizedDetail,
        "description": "Unauthorized"
    }
}
# ...


responses = {
    **the401entry,
    **the404entry,
    **the418entry,
}

meme_responses = {
    **the418entry,
}
```

The `**` operator "spreads" a dictionary. You can see it as removing the braces around it. If you use it inside a dictionary (`responses`) with another dictionary (`the401entry`) it will merge it (what comes last takes priority in case of conflicting keys).

By turning the entry itself `the401entry` into a dictionary, you can reuse it by simply spreading it into wherever you need it. If you need multiple entries in various places always together, you can simply add more entries into the dictionary that you'll spread.